# How to insert only new ( not duplicate ) row to the existing table - in proc sql - sas?

Tags: insert, duplicates, sas

Does any one know how to insert only "new" row to the existing table with in SAS PROC SQL ?

```
proc sql;
 create table class as 
 select * 
 from sashelp.class 
 where sex = 'F'; 
quit;

proc sql;  
 create table classm as 
 select * 
 from sashelp.class 
 where sex = 'M' or Name = 'Alice';
quit;

proc sql;
 insert into class 
 select * 
 from classm ;
quit;
```

The insert statement does not allow me to use where statement to insert only 10 new row from classm ( without Alice )

Is there a way to go around this ? Because I'm working with big data I would like to do this with in proc sql , or data step is fine.

Thanks

Comment: Adding a primary key to your table definition is another way to force the table to reject duplicates. See: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001396785.htm

Comment: I don't quite understand your case here. But it seems that constructing a sophisticated `where` clause like `where (sex = 'M' or Name = 'Alice') or sex = 'F'` could be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
proc sql;
create table class as 
select * 
from sashelp.class 
where sex = 'F'; 
quit;

proc sql;  
create table classm as 
select * 
from sashelp.class 
where sex = 'M' or Name = 'Alice';
quit;

proc sql;
insert into class 
select * 
from classm 
where name^="John";
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use the merge?

you sort your two tables by the columns who are the reference (id) and the merge the two tables with the selected keys.